# Why django page may not load?

Tags: django, vps, python-venv

Project in /root/code/mysite, i activating venv ". ./env/bin/activate", starting server "python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000", all ok
`System check identified no issues (0 silenced). December 25, 2020 - 00:27:24 Django version 2.2.17, using settings 'main.settings' Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/ Quit the server with CONTROL-C.`, but on `http://IP:8000` nothing. What could be the problem?

Comment: You should present a better looking post. Also, some specific details need to be included such as your operating system, the server that you use,your django settings, and any kind of related information. Btw, Do you already open the firewall for your port ?

Comment: Oh, i forgot to open the port, thank you